# How do I serialize Hibernate entities without auto generated fields in test code?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jackson

I have a Hibernate entity with the following fields:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
}
```

I have an endpoint to create employees which I would like to test. To do this I need to send a json representation of the entity but without the id as that is generated by the database.

I would prefer to use `ObjectMapper` to create these representation rather than fiddle with strings myself.

The issue is that `ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(employee)` will include the id in the json. `@JsonIgnore` can’t be used because I need the response from the server to include the id.

The only way around this I can see is to create a custom employee serializer used by the test code such as:

```
public class EmployeeClientSerializer extends StdSerializer<Employee> {
    public EmployeeClientSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public EmployeeClientSerializer(Class<Employee> e) {
        super(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Employee employee, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeStringField("firstName", employee.getFirstName());
        gen.writeStringField("lastName", employee.getLastName());
        gen.writeStringField("email", employee.getEmail());
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Are there any better ways of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a DTO class is really the best option when things get complicated but that also involves mapping from entity to DTO and vice versa.

I am not sure how you intend to serialize your test data. But if your only problem is that there will be  value in `id` it should not be problem and maybe custom serializer is a bit overkill solution. Take a look on this simplified class:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class PrimitiveId {
    private long id;        
    private String firstName;
}
```

because `id` is of type primitive `long` it can not be `null` and is defaulted to **0**. So:

```
PrimitiveId primitiveId = new PrimitiveId();
primitiveId.setFirstName("Primitive");
System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(primitiveId));
```

would print:

> {"id":0,"firstName":"Primitive"}

There is not much you can do this except that do some custom serializing. Except if you change the `id` to boxed `Long`, so like:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class BoxedId {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName; 
}
```

Serializing

```
BoxedId boxedId = new BoxedId();
boxedId.setFirstName("Boxed");
System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(boxedId));
```

would produce now

> {"id":null,"firstName":"Boxed"}

The `null` in `id` would not harm because it would not be serialized, it is `null` after all.

If you really need to get rid of that also, tell it to `ObjectMapper`:

```
om.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL); // serializes only non null values
System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(boxedId));
```

> {"firstName":"Boxed"}

Comment: Yes, DTO didn't come to mind because the request and response json are basically identical. But that would be a much cleaner solution.

For now given it's only id I don't want I'll go with using ```Long``` and look to create a DTO in the future. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DTO object which will represent desired entity class instance without ID field. Then you can create a mapper to handle DTO instance building process automatically(use Mapstruct). Then you can serialize DTO instance with `ObjectMapper` instance.